# Wordpress twenty seventeen custom header style tag

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

On my website on all pages except the home page, here's an example: http://www.pantsdownrecords.com/discography/, the issue I have been having is with the custom header. In the customer header div element where it says: “div class=”custom-header” and right after this is a style tag adding a margin-bottom of 82px. I have looked in all of the template pages and even the few plugins I am running right now, and cannot find where this style tag is being added. And since it is a style tag I can’t override it with CSS since style tags take precedence. Since this margin bottom is there, on some pages I can’t even see the footer because the page can’t scroll to the bottom.

Could somebody help point me in the right direction of where this issue is coming from?
All help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in this file - http://www.pantsdownrecords.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/assets/js/global.js?ver=1.0

Under the `adjustScrollClass()` function. And you can overwrite an inline style with `!important` in your CSS. You should use that feature sparingly, but it works if you need to overwrite an inline style.

Answer (score 0):

You could open more files in `notepad++` and use search with `Find in all open documents` if you want to find a specific string.

You could change this with `CSS` by using `!important`  for the specific element or check with `javascript` or `jQuery` for pages where you have the problem and set the specific styles.

CSS:

`.custom-header { margin-bottom: 0px !important")`

JavaScript:

```
var winURL = window.location.href;
if(winURL == "http://www.pantsdownrecords.com/artists/") {
   document.getElemetsByClassName("custom-header")[0].style.margin = "0px 0px 0px 0px";
}
```

jQuery:

```
var winURL = window.location.href;
if(winURL.indexOf("artist")) {
  $(".custom-header").css("margin","0px");
}
```